# Como funciona o Spliterator no Java 8?

Tags: java, iterator, java-8, spliterator

No Java 8 (que foi lançado em março de 2014), há uma nova interface chamada [Spliterator](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html). Ela tem um propósito semelhante ao [Iterator](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), mas foi projetada para executar iterações em paralelo.

Entretanto, mesmo após ler bastante sobre esta interface e inclusive ter visto alguns códigos de exemplo, ainda não consigo entender como usá-la. Como o Java 8 nem foi lançado ainda (edit: quando fiz esta pergunta em 2013 ainda não havia sido lançado), atualmente existe pouquíssimo material na internet sobre isso. Uma vez que eu tenha alguma estrutura que eu queira iterar em paralelo (por exemplo: uma árvore de busca), como faço para efetivamente obter uma iteração em paralelo usando o Spliterator?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O `Spliterator` parece mais uma classe criada para outras classes mais sofisticadas usarem. A lógica básica está em `trySplit()`, que tenta dividir os elementos restantes em dois `Spliterator`: o corrente e um novo, que o método retorna.

Por exemplo:

```java
void <T> showSize(Spliterator<T> sit) {
  System.out.println("Estimated size for sit: "+sit.getExactSizeIfKnown());
  Spliterator<T> sit2 = sit.trySplit();
  System.out.println("New estimated size for sit: "+sit.getExactSizeIfKnown());
  System.out.println("Estimated size for sit2: "+sit2.getExactSizeIfKnown());
  return;
}
```

O método recebe um `Spliterator`, `sit`, imprime o tamanho (isso pode não funcionar), então divide ele em dois com o `trySplit()`, e imprime os novos tamanhos.

Assumindo que os tamanhos possam ser impressos com precisão, existem duas possibilidades sobre o que se observará:

1. Um erro do tipo `NullPointerException` ao chamar um método em `sit2`, pois não foi possível dividir o `Spliterator`;
2. `sit` e `sit2`, somados, tem o tamanho que `sit` tinha originalmente.

Eu pessoalmente não recomendo tentar usar o `Spliterator` diretamente, pois otimizar esse tipo de coisa é difícil -- por isso mesmo que o `Spliterator` tem coisas como o tipo de coleção, tamanho estimado, processamento sequencial do restante, o fato do `Spliterator` não ser thread-safe, etc.

Se você quer paralelismo, use o `Stream` paralelo. É muito fácil de usar, e toda lógica de otimização já está embutida.

Comment: *Daniel*, você sabe que critério o método trySplit() usa para fazer essa *divisão*?

Comment: @GeisonSantos Depende da implementação. Em algo como um `ArrayList`, provavelmente ele divide pela metade.

Comment: As vezes você precisa _acessar_ um `Spliterator`, como fazer processamento paralelo a partir de um `Iterable`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345434/64969; na prática, entretanto, só vi como um meio para chamar `StreamSupport`, sem maiores mudanças referentes a isso. Digamos que, apesar de ter acessado, eu não usei de fato o `Spliterator` na resposta, e ele continua sendo uma caixa preta pra mim

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;

public class SpliteratorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList("Apple","Banana", "Orange", "Guava");
        
        Spliterator<String> spliterator1 = wordList.spliterator();
        Spliterator<String> spliterator2 = spliterator1.trySplit();
        
        spliterator1.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("Traversing the other of the spliterator...");
        spliterator2.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
Orange  
Guava  
Traversing the other of the spliterator...  
Apple  
Banana
```

Para mais informação acesse [este link](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/java-spliterator/).