# Dividir Array em várias Threads

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Preciso fazer uma Query em meu Banco de dados, que retornará cada uma das Linhas. No entanto, para cada uma delas, durante o Retorno, preciso aguardar cerca de 5 segundos, pois é o tempo que preciso esperar para o Ping concluir e me retornar se o Host está ou não de pé.

```
@GetMapping
public Iterable<MonitoriaEntidade> resposta() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

    Iterable<MonitoriaEntidade> findAll = monitoriaRepositorio.findAll();

    for (MonitoriaEntidade monitoriaEntidade : findAll) {
        if (InetAddress.getByName(monitoriaEntidade.getIp()).isReachable(5000)) monitoriaEntidade.setStatus(true);
    }

    return findAll;
}
```

Minha dúvida, é: Como faço para separar essa Query em várias Threads diferentes, para que eu não faça apenas uma de cada vez, mas, de preferência, o quanto o Servidor conseguir.

Comment: Você tem que ter um pool de conexões com o banco, ou seja, cada _thread_ vai ter que separadamente fazer a sua chamada para o banco e fazer a pesquisa, já que cada conexão suporta apenas um objeto (a chamada). Quanto às _threads_, pesquise por `ExecutorService`, que é uma API _core_ do Java para lidar com um _pool_ de _threads_ de maneira assíncrona. Dê uma olhada em `CompletableFuture` também, que é para o retorno assíncrono do seu método (a sua busca) ser armazenado e manipulado.

Comment: @StatelessDev, para a parte em threads, creio que seja melhor mesmo é usar `parallelStream`. Isso evita você, como programador, ter de lidar explicitamente com o paralelismo, quando esse paralelismo em específico tem todo o jeito de ser totalmente não concorrente. Parece-me um típico cenário que só preciso esperar pelos `joins` das threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer através de uma `stream` em paralelo. Mas, para tal, primeiro se faz necessário "esconder" a exceção para uma `RuntimeException` ([leia mais](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-exceptions)).

Vamos por uma RTE que carregue `UnknownHostException` ou `IOException`, para usá-la dentro da expressão lambda:

```
class WrapperException extends RuntimeException {
    final UnknownHostException uhe;
    final IOException ioe;

    WrapperException(UnknownHostException uhe) {
      super(uhe);
      this.uhe = uhe;
      this.ioe = null;
    }

    WrapperException(IOException ioe) {
      super(ioe);
      this.uhe = null;
      this.ioe = ioe;
    }

    void throwWrappedException() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
      if (this.uhe != null) throw uhe;
      if (this.ioe != null) throw ioe;
    }
}
```

Agora, vamos transformar a parte interna do seu laço em um método que não lance exceção checadas, que as transforme em `WrapperException`:

```
void setStatusMonitoriaEntidade(MonitoriaEntidade monitoriaEntidade) {
  try {
    if (InetAddress.getByName(monitoriaEntidade.getIp()).isReachable(5000)) {
      monitoriaEntidade.setStatus(true);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new WrapperException(e);
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    throw new WrapperException(e);
  }
}
```

Então, se hipoteticamente o método `findAll` retornasse uma `Collection` (como uma `List`), podemos transformar esse laço `for` em um `parallelStream`:

```
@GetMapping
public List<MonitoriaEntidade> resposta() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    List<MonitoriaEntidade> findAll = monitoriaRepositorio.findAll();

    try {
      findAll.parallelStream().forEach(this::setStatusMonitoriaEntidade);
    } catch (WrapperException e) {
      // se um dos processamentos der ruim, lança a exceção; mesmo comportamento anterior
      e.throwWrappedException();
    }

    return findAll;
}
```

Em meus experimentos (não encontrei a documentação oficial sobre o assunto), fazer essas chamadas através de `parallelStream` usa o máximo de núcleos disponíveis para processamento, mas não cria `threads` além do que pode de fato ser consumido.

Em compensação, não é o caso, como você me lembrou. Entretanto, quase nada está perdido. Tem um ótimo [artigo do Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-iterable-to-stream) sobre o assunto. Ele resolve isso usando [`StreamSupport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html):

```
@GetMapping
public Iterable<MonitoriaEntidade> resposta() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Iterable<MonitoriaEntidade> findAll = monitoriaRepositorio.findAll();

    try {
      StreamSupport.stream(findAll.spliterator(), true).forEach(this::setStatusMonitoriaEntidade);
    } catch (WrapperException e) {
      // se um dos processamentos der ruim, lança a exceção; mesmo comportamento anterior
      e.throwWrappedException();
    }

    return findAll;
}
```

Comment: Excelente, Jefferson. Apenas um detalhe bobo que você certamente sabe: dá para usar o operador lógico `|` no `catch`, pegando as duas exceções e economizando um `catch` e um `throw` com isso.

Comment: @StatelessDev eu só quis garantir a chamada correta do construtor. Como escrevi isto sem estar em um computador, fiquei com dúvidas se o `javac` conseguiria resolver corretamente qual dos construtores chamar, então preferi ser explícito. Eu não sei qual vai ser o tipo de `e` usando o `multi-catch` quando for resolver qual construtor chamar...

Comment: O problema que estou tendo, é que o Método parallelStream() não está disponível no Iterable, o que eu preciso fazer para poder usá-lo?

Comment: @FernandoCampanate perdão minha displicência, juro que tinha visto `Collection` ou `List`. Você precisa transformar numa `Stream` e paralelizar. Vou editar a resposta

Comment: @FernandoCampanate como você voltou a marcar minha resposta como aceita, estou julgando que deram certo seus testes. Confere? Se restou qualquer dúvida sobre as coisas nesta resposta, ou se tiver algo na sua dúvida ainda não contemplado, pode por aqui que tentarei complementar a resposta

Comment: Consegui implementar o que você falou, mas ainda estou tentando fazer funcionar. Pois antes eu não estava usando o Lambda, assim que tiver uma conclusão, te respondo aqui.

Comment: FUNCIONOU!!! E extremamente rápido!